# How to set different fonts for tables and algorithms

Tags: pdftex

I am writing my thesis. The 'documentclass' is

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside]{ducs}
```

I have a large algorithm that can be adjusted to one page by using '\small' font size. For this I used

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]\small
```

However, '\small' is not working. The same holds for large tables. I need help to override the existing font size which is 12 in my `algorithm`s, `table`s, and `colorbox` as well.

Comment: Where is the `ducs` class available?

Comment: It's not publicly available.

Comment: Sorry, in this case you're on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To long for the comment.

Command `\small` had to be before table or your algorithm code. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize   % that change of the font size is better visible
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rl}
\hline
 1  &   some text   \\
11  &   some text   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[12]

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\footnotesize   % that change of the font size iz better visible
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:*
In MWE is selected `footnotesize` font size that their size changes is better visible.

Comment: You should explain that the group is needed to change locally the size.